# Windows 10 provisioning package applied but not working

Tags: windows-10, xml

I set up a simple provisioning package for a multi-app kiosk in Windows 10 Pro 1803. The package installs without any visible errors, but when I login with the specified user none of my changes took.

Here is the XML I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AssignedAccessConfiguration 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config"
    xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"
    >
    <Profiles>
        <Profile Id="{dd1bc1ea-43fa-4173-9422-ecb7e4e56eb3}">
            <AllAppsList>
                <AllowedApps/>
                    <App DesktopAppPath="%SystemDrive%\Users\Public\SEAGULL\J Walk Windows Client\4.1038.1.822\jw9c.exe" />
                    <App DesktopAppPath="%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" rs5:AutoLaunch="true" />
                <AllowedApps/>
            </AllAppsList>         
            <StartLayout/>
            <Taskbar ShowTaskbar="false"/>
        </Profile>
    </Profiles>
    <Configs>
        <Config>
            <Account>domain\account</Account>
            <DefaultProfile Id="{fb2bbe2e-07d1-494d-9431-0b86e7ea75fe}"/>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
</AssignedAccessConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the Profile ID to the account that's supposed to use it:

```
...
<Config>
        <Account>domain\account</Account>
        <DefaultProfile Id="{dd1bc1ea-43fa-4173-9422-ecb7e4e56eb3}"/>
</Config>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got caught up on another project. I used the whoami\user cmd to pull the ID of the user, but that still didn't work.